# How do I install an older version of Mono 5.20 from Mono repo on Centos7?

Tags: mono

Mono website suggested this
On RPM distributions, force the package version in your package manager - all older versions are published in the YUM metadata and should be available.

I have no idea how to go about the above?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to install a specific version? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151689/how-can-i-instruct-yum-to-install-a-specific-version-of-package-x

Comment: I tried this yum install  mono-core-5.20.1.34-0.xamarin.2.epel7, but it stop stating dependencies, not sure what argument to use to force dependencies install as well.